# This estimator, why is it good?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I've been given the following as an estimate for the parameter of a Poisson distribution, and must explain why it is a sensible estimate.

$$\log\left(\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n 2^{x_i} \right)               $$

I'm pretty confused because I've covered method of moments estimators and the MLE, but this looks like neither of those. Any advice as to what I'm missing would be much appreciated.

Note: The log is the natural logarithm - they like to use that instead of ln for clarity and say that ln can easily confuse some expressions.

Comment: Is that $\log(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{X_i})$? Base of $\log$? Maybe explore geometric mean.

Comment: I guess the logarithm base is two?

Comment: It should be natural log. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

First off, I don't believe this estimator is "good". The sample mean is the best unbiased estimator for $\lambda$. But I can offer you some intuition behind why this estimator is "reasonable".

Let $Y_i = 2^{X_i}$. Then the estimator you propose is basically: $ln(\bar{Y})$.

Now we consider $\mathbb{E}[\bar{Y}]$.

$\mathbb{E}[\bar{Y}] = \mathbb{E}[Y_i] = \mathbb{E}[2^X] = \sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{2^xe^{-\lambda} \lambda^x}{x!} = \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{e^{-2\lambda}}\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{(2\lambda)^xe^{-2\lambda}}{x!} = e^{-\lambda + 2\lambda} = e^\lambda$

If the expected value of $\bar{Y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n2^{x_i}$ is $e^\lambda$, then it makes sense to take the natural log of $\bar{Y}$.

---

Here is an example setting $\lambda = 10$. Sampling distributions are plotted for the sample mean (black), the estimator described above (blue) and the estimator if you use $log_2$ instead of $ln$ (green).

[image: Comparing Estimators]

Comment: First, you seem to be mixing bases (the logarithm should be in base 2). Second,  there is no "best estimator", strictly speaking, it all depends on your measure of "quality". Third, why do you say that $E(Y_i)=e^\lambda$ ?

Comment: @leonbloy Nope. Not getting my logarithms mixed up. Try it and you'll see that I'm right. And true.. but the sample mean is the "best" unbiased estimator (UMVUE), and will be the "best" according to most reasonable criteria.

Comment: I added some detail to the Expected value calculation. So that you can see more easily what is going on.

Comment: Thank for the help, and I agree. Having found the approximation to the bias and standard error, the estimator didn't seem all that good to me. I was a bit stuck, so cheers!